# wp-cron vs server cron (max execution time)

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I would like to ask you about differences between wp-cron and server cron. Basically I have a php script which takes some minutes to complete. If I run it through browser, browser shows error something about timeout.

So I put it into server cron (paid hosting) and it is working.

I was trying set_time_limit... when was accessing through browser but it did not work...

Anyway I want to execute this script lets say every 2 weeks. I know that wordpress has wp-cron, but my question is it is good as server cron? Will it work for long time scripts?

Because of my point of view the wp-cron is initialized by user (browser) so it should apply limits in php.ini right?

Because it is paid hosting I can not modify a lot of options...

So what is the difference between these crons?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, wp-cron is initialized by the browser.  Therefore, it will only execute for 30 seconds by default.  Therefore, it is not meant for running scripts that may take longer than a few second.

Server cron runs your script from the command line which does not have same time constraint.
From everything you have said your script is a good candidate to run as a server cron.